# Using std::make_array with C structs

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have been experimenting with [std::make_array()](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4391.html), and overall very happy with the results.  The code is a little cleaner and I don't have to specify the array size as a template parameter.

One unknown I've run into is how to use make_array with raw C structs.  For example,

```
struct Point {
    int x, y;
};

auto triangle = std::make_array<point>({3, 3}, {5, 5}, {1, 5});
```

I can get this to work if I create a constexpr constructor for Point.  This isn't always an option - some of my structs are defined in headers used by C code.  Using std::array's constructor works fine.  Is there any way to get this to work with std::make_array?

Comment: `to_array<Point>({{3, 3}, {5, 5}, {1, 5}});`. This overload of `to_array` is not included in N4391, but its implementation is present in https://gist.github.com/lichray/6034753 .

Comment: if you're assigning to constexpr variable then I don't see how you could think there is another way

Comment: @Sopel, I didn't think constexpr would matter, as it works fine with regular types, so I ran a test and it still wouldn't build.  I've removed constexpr from the example to clarify.

Comment: @cpplearner, that implementation of to_array did indeed work.  If you want to submit that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.  Do you know any details on the difference between to_array and make_array?  I've seen references to both but no clear distinctions on when to use one vs the other.